# Is it possible to run Anaconda script from C# Form App?

Tags: python, c#

I am creating C# Form app and I want to create a button which will help me to run an anaconda script when clicked.

My desired script: "python AllInOne.py"

Can I run this script on a C# Form button, if it is so; how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void run_cmd(string cmd, string args)
{
     ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
     start.FileName = "my/full/path/to/python.exe";
     start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
     start.UseShellExecute = false;
     start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     using(Process process = Process.Start(start))
     {
         using(StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
         {
             string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
             Console.Write(result);
         }
     }
}
```

OR

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

private static void doPython()
{
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    engine.ExecuteFile(@"AllInOne.py");
}
```